# Worst case scenario of each algorithm

Tags: performance, sorting

I am trying to list out what the worst case input arrays/Scenarios for each algorithm would be and I could use some help...

- Merge - ?
- Selection - Array is in reverse order?
- Quick - The pivot is the smallest or biggest element.
- Insertion - Array is in reverse order?
- Radix -?
- Counting - All elements are the same?

Comment: You forgot to explain what specific problem you had when trying to do this by yourself.

Comment: Radix sort worst case is related to random access outside of cached memory, so on each pass, the pattern of the numbers results in writes outside of cached memory. Normally random numbers will cause this. A counting sort would face the same random access issue if the range of values requires an array large than would fit in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good link I found... https://prosuncsedu.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/best-case-and-worst-case-situation-of-sorting-algorithms/